# Passing an actual view type rather than AnyView

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a View that has an `innerView` which displays `AnyView` inside the `MessageView` wrapper:

```
struct MessageView: View, Identifiable {
  let id = UUID()
  var side: MessageBubbleSide = .left
  let innerView: AnyView
  var hasBackground = true

  var body: some View {
    HStack {
      innerView
        .padding(.horizontal, .five)
        .padding(.vertical, .five)
        .messageBubble(
          displayFrom: side,
          hasBackground: hasBackground
        )
      Spacer()
    }
    .transition(.move(edge: side == .left ? .leading : .trailing))
    .animation(.spring())
  }
}
```

I then have an array of different `MessageViews` each containing different types of innerViews that are cast to an `AnyView`:

```
let one = MessageView(
  innerView: AnyView(
    Text("Some text here.")
  )
)
response.append(one)

let three = MessageView(
  innerView: AnyView(
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: .two) {
      Text("Some text here")
      Text("And some more.")
    }
  )
)
response.append(two)
```

This array of `MessageViews` is turned into a `Publisher` which is then emitted over time and displays on screen.

Is there any way I can stop having to wrap the `innerView` in an `AnyView`? I thought about `@ViewBuilder`, but that needs a generic and then these generic `MessageViews` can't be added into an array.

Comment: You can't have "array of different MessageViews" with different types `innerView`, so answer is No. However if you would not need to store them into one-type container, then yes it is possible by converting MessageView into generics by inner view type.

Comment: @Asperi Ah that's a shame. Thank you